# Flutter Firebase How to integrate third party authentication that generates a token

Tags: firebase, authentication, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a third party API that generates a token that lasts 60mins. I want to use the token to retrieve user information from the third party database which I want to save in Firestone so I can query later and take advantage of Firestore features like offline data persistence, notifications to specific user info, and analytics.

In order to generate this token, I give the input parameters of:
cardNumber (int)
PIN (int)

How do I create a Firestore user while using a third party API that generates a token? What’s the best way to go about copying the user information into the user on Firebase? Cloud function?

I couldn’t find any guides with flutter and am confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication ID tokens are JWTs that are signed with your Firebase project's credentials. In the case of [custom authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth), you mint that token, and then sign in to Firebase with [`signInWithCustomToken`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signInWithCustomToken.html).

If the third party API already delivers such a JWT signed with the correct key, it should work as is. More often the third party API will use a different format, and you will have to [mint the JWT yourself](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) [using the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) or one of the [third party libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library). Since this is a sensitive operation, it should only be done in a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions.